# The error/success message alert does not show up on 2nd ajax call without refreshing page again in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

This is `click event` of `Submit/Send` button in `modal` when I click on send button if the email field is empty it shows the error that `Please enter valid Email(s).` If email field is not empty and email is valid it shows the success message that `An email has been sent to your friend.` after sending email to that email and closes the modal because of that `setTimeout function` but when again I open that modal and clicks send button it does not show any error message or success message even though email is sent. I have to refresh the page to make it work again. What is wrong in my code?

```
$('#send-book').on('click', function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?route=account/books/shareWithFriends',
       type: 'post',
       data: 'emails=' + $("#friends-emails").val() +'&booklink=' + $("#sharedBookUrl").val(),
       dataType: 'json',
     beforeSend: function() {
       $('#send-book').button('loading');
     },
     success: function(json) {
       var newDta = JSON.stringify(json);
       var msg = '';
       if (json['error']) {
        msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>" +
             "<strong>ERROR!</strong> " +
             json['error'] +
             "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>" +
             "</div>";
       }
       if (json['success']) {
         msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" +
               "<strong>Success!</strong> " +
               json['success'] +
               "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>" +
               "</div>";
       }
       $('#book-shared-message').html(msg);
       setTimeout(function() {
          $("#book-shared-message").hide();
          $('#tellYourFriendModel').modal('hide');
       }, 3000);
       $('#friends-emails').val('');
       $('#send-book').button('reset');
     }
   });
});
```

**UPDATE :**

```
/* code to handle show modal popup for tell your friend */
    $('a[id^="tellYourFriend-"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentThis = $(this);
        var book_url = currentThis.attr('data-book_url');
        $('#sharedBookUrl').val(book_url);
        //$('#book-shared-message').html('');
        $('#tellYourFriendModel').modal('show');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `.hide()` on the `#book-shared-message` element, but it never calls `.show()` to show it again. So when you fill it with a new value using `.html(msg)` it is still invisible. You should probably call `.show()` every time you display it.

Similarly, you call `$('#tellYourFriendModel').modal('hide');` which appears to be something to hide the modal overlay, but shouldn't there be some kind of corresponding `.modal('show')` call? I'm not familiar with this plugin so can't give you the specifics, but it does look suspicious.

BTW, this is something you could figure out on your own by using the DOM inspector from the developer tools in any browser. If you inspected your DOM elements after the second submit, you would see that some of them are hidden.

Comment: I have edited my question and added code where .modal('show') is called

Comment: Very good - but I still don't see anywhere that you `.show()` the `#book-shared-message` after hiding it.

Comment: let me do that in ajax complete  and test, will let you know in just 5 minutes

Comment: It worked , Thanks Sir! Going to accept your answer!

Comment: Great! I'm glad that was helpful. One more thought... I don't know how your elements are nested, but if `#book-shared-message` is a _child_ of the `#tellYourFriendModel`, then you may not need to hide it at all, since hiding its parent would hide it too. This would simplify the code a bit. Also, just a spelling nit, you probably want to name the modal div `tellYourFriendModal`, not `tellYourFriendModel`. :-)

Comment: I was working on other developers code who spelled it like that :-)

Comment: Roger that. Then shall we just say... They were not _model_ developers! ;-)